# Java - Compute cubic Hermite spline with 2nd derivative = 0 at endpoints

Tags: java, spline

I might be missing something really basic here, but is it possible compute a cubic Hermite Spline between two points (position and tangent given) with the 2nd derivative equal to 0 at the endpoints (so that it has C2 continuity with a line segment)? Or, would I need a higher degree spline to accomplish this? After a few hours of research, I seem to be getting mixed answers.

I have no experience with splines and spline fit, so even if it is possible, I have no idea how to accomplish this arithmetically or programmatically. I also have no clue whether I provided enough information, so feel free to request for anything I need to supply. Any help or additional resources would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: After some more research, it appears that I am asking for a cubic spline between two points that can be both relaxed (second derivative = 0 at both endpoints) and clamped (first derivative is explicitly defined at both endpoints). Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, sorry but SO is for *specific* programming questions.  This is too broad.  Maybe try http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Yup. Funny you say that, I was just making a post for them now. I'll be back if I have trouble implementing algorithms that I find.

Answer (score 0):

[Paul Bourke](http://paulbourke.net/) has a page on [interpolation methods](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/) that includes hermite interpolation. The listed code is for 1D, but it should give you an idea of the basic structure. Replacing `double` with a 2D (or 3D) type is doable, but Java's lack of operator overloading will require some slight changes (replacing operators with function calls).

Comment: I just edited my main post again, as I realize I was still not explaining exactly what I wanted. I am asking for a cubic spline between two points that can be both relaxed (second derivative = 0 at both endpoints) and clamped (first derivative is explicitly defined at both endpoints). Is this possible?